# C++ and Fortran: Error accessing arrays in a Fortran common block from C++

Tags: c++, fortran, integration, fortran-common-block

I'm trying to access an array within a Fortran common block structure from C++.
I have a mixed sample code with C++ and Fortran.

Fortran:

```
integer a(5),b  
common  /sample/ a,b  
a(1) = 1  
a(2) = 5  
a(3) = 10  
a(4) = 15  
a(5) = 20  
b = 25
```

Then in C++:

```
extern "C"{  
    extern struct{  
        int *a,b;  
}sample_;
```

From C++, if I try to print the value `sample_.b`:

```
printf("sample b:%d\n",sample_.b);
```

I get the value of a(2) : `sample b:5`

And if I try to print any other of the array-a values I just get a segementation fault...

```
printf("sample_.a[1]=%d\n",(int)sample_.a[1]);  
printf("sample_.a[0]=%d\n",(int)sample_.a[0]);
```

What am I doing wrong?¿ Any idea ¿?
I think, maybe I have to pass the length of the array "a" too to C++, but if so, I don't know how to do it either.

Comment: You are not passing the array to the C++ code. You are directly accessing the common block as an external structure. Please, correct your question accordingly. I've already corrected the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Fortran is a bit (OK, QUITE a bit) rusty, but let me give it a whirl.

`a` probably received the VALUE rather than a pointer to it. That would set it to `1`, which not a good pointer value.

`b` received the second value in the data block. Your C++ struct gives no indication to the compiler what the real format of the data is, so it's going to just mindlessly assign the items to the structure in the order given in the struct. I'd get a pointer to the data block and disassemble it by hand.

Assign `a` to the ADDRESS of the data block (as a `long int` pointer, looks like; your mileage may vary) and `b = a[5]`. Hope that helps.

Comment: OOPS; probably should be a pointer to an int (sorry). If you assign a correctly, a[1] should be 5.

Comment: Close, he's not receiving anything "by-value", but rather in a `COMMON` block the data is laid out sequentially and is contiguous. Basically, the C/C++ structure equivalent of arrays in a `COMMON` block is a flat array.

Comment: Yeah, if it was "by value" it'd be different. What he's getting is the address of a data block. Picking it apart with an integer array is still what I'd do; however, I'm too lazy to fiddle around with mappings. Also, my last Fortran program was written in the '70's. ;)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to share global variables between C and Fortran, the best way is to use module variables and the Fortran ISO_C_Binding.  Common blocks are a relic, best avoided unless part of legacy code.   Using the ISO_C_Binding will make your code compiler and platform independent.  There is a code example in the subsection "Interoperable Global Variables" of the chapter "Mixed Language Programming" of the gfortran manual.  This isn't specific to gfortran, just some good documentation.

Continuing with the ISO_C_Binding, if you use the Fortran types that it provides you will be ensured of a match to the C types.   The Fortran equivalent to C's **int** is **C_INT**.   A list appears in the chapter "Intrinsic Modules" of the gfortran manual.

Comment: Unfortunately there are millions of lines of relic FORTRAN 77 code and it's not always possible to have it rewritten in Fortran 2003.

Comment: I don't disagree with this, but eh, it answer's horstmann's question in a rather circumspect fashion.

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like your FORTRAN data is actually laid out as

```
struct {
  int a[5];
  int b;
}
```

and you are on a machine where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: +1, members of a `COMMON` block are usually (without messing with compiler options) laid out sequentially in memory. Therefore, when given the starting address for the `COMMON` block `SAMPLE`, the array `A` will be contiguous with `B`.

Comment: One should pay attention to alignment of data. By default Fortran compilers do not align COMMON blocks members with padding but that might change if aggressive optimisation options are supplied. Hence one must ensure that the C/C++ structure has the same alignment of its fields should optimisations have been used on the Fortran side.

Answer (score 0):

thak you all for your useful anwers. Following your advices I finally realized what my problem was. I think my mistake was that in Fortran I had:

```
integer a(5),b  
common  /sample/ a,b
```

`a(5)` with a fixed size, and then in C++:

```
extern "C"{  
    extern struct{  
        int *a,b;  
}sample_;
```

`*a` without size, as a pointer. Thus, the compiler was understanding a this way, as a `*int` pointer instead of as an `a(5)` array

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Given their answers solved your problem, you should accept [Christopher's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10482608/7116) or [Joe's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10482194/7116) answer. You can do this by clicking the Checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

For a proper C++/Fortran code you should use at least Fortran 2003. It is actually quite straightforward to create a Fortran 2003/2008 interface for an old Fortran code (even for Fortran 77).

Here is a link to a post about mixing modern Fortran and C++:

http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/05/11/mixed-language-programming-cpp-11-fortran-2008/